# How to send a notification based on spinner value on android app?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm doing my final year project about flood push notification. Previously, a user will retrieve notifications whenever the value in database changes from 0 to 1. But right now,in my app, the user can choose which places he parks his car and he can retrieved status and notification based on the park's place whether it's zero or one. As for example, User A set his spinner value in Mid Valley and User B set his spinner value in KPS. User A will get notification when FLOOD_STATUS_MID_VALLEY is 1, while User B didn't receive any notifications because FLOOD_STATUS_KPS is still 0. Anyone can help me on how to send notification based on the spinner value in the app?

Screenshot of my app
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xapsa.png)

below is the python code that running on server to send notification based on a value called "FLOOD_STATUS" in firebase database

```
from pusher_push_notifications import PushNotifications
config = {
    'apiKey': "APIKEY",
    'authDomain': "car-app-push-notification.firebaseapp.com",
    'databaseURL': "https://car-app-push-notification.firebaseio.com",
    'projectId': "car-app-push-notification",
    'storageBucket': "car-app-push-notification.appspot.com",
    'messagingSenderId': "596729642105",
    'appId': "APPID",
    'measurementId': "G-9LMJGS1BDW"
  }
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

beams_client = PushNotifications(
    instance_id='49f62b05-bd81-4040-ab57-80afa56a8680',
    secret_key='SECRET KEY',
)

def stream_handler(message):
    print(message)
    if(message['data'] is 1):
        response = beams_client.publish_to_interests(
            interests=['hello'],
            publish_body={
                'apns': {
                    'aps': {
                        'alert': 'Hello!',
                    },
                },
                'fcm': {
                    'notification': {
                        'title': 'Alert!',
                        'body': 'It is starting to flood, please remove your car immediately!',
                    },
                },
            },
        )

        print(response['publishId'])
my_stream = db.child("FLOOD_STATUS").stream(stream_handler,None)
```

Comment: Also in your screenshot, consider changing the text to *"Please let this app run in the background without closing it to get emergency notifications!"*

Comment: @samthecodingman alright, thanks for that suggestion. done change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is your FYP, I won't provide any code for this.

When a **user changes where they parked**, you will want to **change their device interest** to match the relevant location.

When the `FLOOD_STATUS` is **updated to `1`** for a **given location**, you send the notification **to the matching interest**.

Comment: currently in my firebase database have 3 value, FLOOD_STATUS_MID_VALLEY, FLOOD_STATUS_KPS and FLOOD_STATUS_PPUM. i don't know how to send the notification via server to the user app according to the matching interest. help me please

Comment: okay i already found the solution,by removeDeviceInterest and addDeviceInterest on the spinner selected item then send the notification based on the interest. thanks for giving me the idea

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that, when the user A select the `MID_VALLEY` in the `Spinner` you send the selected value to the server. I recommend you to have a look on [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/2S2ZyqLVn10) to see how to get the selected value from `Spinner`
At server side, when the `FLOOD_STATUS_MID_VALLEY` is 1 you only send the notification to the user A(because you knew the `FCM token` of the user A).

If you want to custom the item of Spinner you can watch [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/TmA1t941rNE).

Comment: thanks for the reply, i want to ask how do i send the selected value to the server? and is the can we make FCM token change based on spinner selected item? It's like have 3 fcm token since have 3 place. is it possible?

Comment: While I like this approach and it would work, it is easier and simpler to just subscribe and unsubscribe to the relevant notification interest (group) as you won't have to iterate the database for a list of relevant users before sending out the notification.